# How to give certain users access to your admin site on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

**Background:**

In my company, we have one firebase project which is linked to our iOS application and an internal tool(purely for our use and not the consumers). Now since the database is common to both the website and the iOS app, all the users who create an account on the iOS application automatically have access to our internal tool. I wish to allow only a handful of people or one person to have access to the internal tool.

**Question:**

Is there a way for me to give certain users access to the internal tool? (If it involves manually giving them access from the firebase console?)
Is there a way to make the user authentication check different for the internal tool?

Comment: You should take a look at [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) as that's what you need to control access to data in your Firebase. The rule for this case would be to have a */users* node in your database and keep a child node 'web_access: true'. Craft a security rule to checks to see if the user should have web access (validate that node is set to true) and if so, allow them to access the data from the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) let you specify custom access to database or tools.

You can specify an `admin` role to those users who should have access to the admin tool and make sure they have this role in your app's route (or route guard)